# Typescript related keyof T types are not assignable to each other

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a simple event dispatcher class which uses a method similar to `addEventListener` on the DOM type definitions combined with an event map that maps an event name to an event class.

```js
interface EventMap {
  [type: string]: any // tslint:disable-line no-any
}

type Listener<T, K extends keyof T> = (event: T[K]) => void

export class Dispatcher<T extends EventMap, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  /**
   * The current list of listeners.
   */
  private listeners: { [key: string]: Listener<T, K>[] } = {}

  /**
   * Add a new event listener.
   *
   * @param type The type of event to list to.
   * @param listener The function that should be called when the event is dispatched.
   */
  addEventListener<EventType extends K> (type: EventType, listener: Listener<T, EventType>): void {
    // Workaround: Type 'EventType' cannot be used to index type '{ [key: string]: Listener<T, K>[]; }'
    const key: string = type as string
    if (! (key in this.listeners)) {
      this.listeners[key] = []
    }

    this.listeners[key].push(listener)
  }

  /**
   * Remove an event listener.
   *
   * @param type The type of event to remove a listener for. If no listener is
   * given, all event listeners for this type will be removed.
   * @param listener The listener to remove.
   */
  removeEventListener<EventType extends K> (type: EventType, listener?: Listener<T, EventType>): void {
    const key: string = type as string
    if (! (key in this.listeners)) {
      return
    }

    if (listener) {
      const index = this.listeners[key].indexOf(listener)
      if (index === -1) {
        return
      }

      this.listeners[key].splice(index, 1)
    } else {
      delete this.listeners[key]
    }
  }

  /**
   * Dispatch an event.
   *
   * @param type The type of event to dispatch.
   * @param event The event payload.
   */
  dispatch<EventType extends K> (type: EventType, event: T[EventType]): void {
    const key: string = type as string
    if (! (key in this.listeners)) {
      return
    }

    this.listeners[key].forEach(listener => listener(event))
  }
}
```

It would be used something like this:

```js
class ChangeEvent {
  constructor (public readonly value: string) {
  }
}

interface EventMap {
  'change': ChangeEvent
}

const dispatcher = new Dispatcher<EventMap>()
```

This works well, but since updating to Typescript 3.4 (from 3.3), I get a type error on the lines adding and looking up event listeners on the listeners array, the `push` and `indexOf` calls.

```
Argument of type 'Listener<T, EventType>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Listener<T, K>'.
  Type 'K' is not assignable to type 'EventType'.
    Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'EventType'.
      Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'EventType'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'EventType'.
```

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't see what. `EventType` extends `K`, so why does this not work? It especially does not make sense to me that "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'EventType'", as `keyof T` will surely include `string`.

Comment: It looks fine to me. If the exact same code works in ts v3.3 but breaks in v3.4, then it's more likely a bug rather than your fault.

Comment: @hackape Thanks for the feedback, reported it as an issue on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30828